# Apple push notification sandbox

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I read in the official apple [page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130424034516/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html), that:

> The sandbox environment also acts a virtual device, enabling simulated
>   end-to-end testing

but in many blogs I read that you still need an iPhone or iPad or iPod touch to test my push notifications application.

Do I really need an Apple device for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deviceTokenBinary` is a variable which is generated per device and cannot be created using a simulator

Check the **The Binary Interface and Notification Formats** in [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html)

Answer (score 4):

The sandbox environment works with the development certificate only. Also that you need to build a app with the development certificate. The next thing that needs to be done is provisioning of mobile devices using the device's UDID on which the app will be installed. After you install it, then the app will give you the device token(there is no other way that you can get a valid device token)i.e Yes, you need a device if you want to see the push or get the device token.

Also that the device token is generated by the combination of app and the device, so no other way is possible rather than installing the app on a device.

For more installation and tutorial i have found a nice website which you can surely check here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

Please do have a look over it. :)